# How to persist Google API Credentials in a flutter SPA

Tags: flutter, google-api

I'm trying to create a flutter web app that accesses Google Cloud Platform. This is a client side application. I'd like the user to not have to go through a sign in flow each time they open the application or refresh the page. What is the correct approach on the web?

In desktop applications, I use the [OAuth AuthFlow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app) to obtain a refresh credential which I store in the home directory.

In a web application should I also obtain an refresh token and store that using [flutter secure storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage)?

I tried following the [Google APIs Flutter Example](https://pub.dev/packages/extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth/example). This works but every time I refresh the page I have to call `_googleSignIn.signIn()` in order to obtain a credential; invoking `_googleSignIn.signInSilently()` doesn't appear to be sufficient. I see a pop-up indicating automatic sign in but the user account still ends up being null and I have to explicitly call `signIn()`. Is this working as expected or does it indicate some other bug in my application?

Is the GoogleSignIn flow using the implicit flow? I looked at the code but couldn't really find where the OAuth flow was happening. [GoogleSignIn](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/32c120ff6af7152cd7c4dc218b404558395efd5c/packages/extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth/lib/extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth.dart#L26) indicates there is no refresh token which suggests to me the implicit flow.

Comment: No, users don't have to sign in every time. There is a problem somewhere in your code, but we can't see it :)

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide a bit more context about how this is supposed to work? Is it in fact using the [implicit flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/choose-authorization-model#oauth_20_flow_comparison). If a user gesture is needed to refresh the credential then it seems like this might be the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OAuth documentation](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/single-page-apps/) seems pretty clear that the OAuth2 authorization code flow with PKCE is the recommended approach for web apps. [Auth0 docs](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/implicit-flow-with-form-post) and [Microsoft migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/migrate-spa-implicit-to-auth-code) documentation support this.

Based on this I don't think [GoogleSignIn](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/32c120ff6af7152cd7c4dc218b404558395efd5c/packages/extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth/lib/extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth.dart#L26) is the right package to use as I believe its using the implicit flow.

Here's a working [example](https://github.com/jlewi/flutter_oauth) using the [oauth2_client](https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2_client/example) package. This package automatically stores the credentials in local storage. In order to obtain a refresh token you need to request offline access as indicated [here](https://github.com/jlewi/flutter_oauth/blob/27aa1c02aceea26ded257f5853fb40af9d2872bf/lib/gcp.dart#L34).

Comment: I filed [flutter/flutter#](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123485) to hopefully update the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Using flutter web is kinda tricky, you need to have clear that anytime you refresh the webpage the app will rebuild completely so you need to save that token/auth state on local storage or secure storage.

Comment: Thanks. Is [GoogleSignInAuthentication](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/32c120ff6af7152cd7c4dc218b404558395efd5c/packages/google_sign_in/google_sign_in/lib/google_sign_in.dart#L20) the right thing to persist?  ISTM that this is using the implicit flow which IUC is not recommended for [SPAs](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/implicit-flow-with-form-post) except for login. Does flutter have a suitable library for the Auth flow?